# How to get immediate child in cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to parse through an awful website and I need some help with using cheerio.

I know that if I for example want to get html of a body of a html I do

```
 $('body','html').html();
```

How do I descend through multiple elements?

(What if I want to get html > body > font > table > tbody > tr ?)

!! Have to be careful with all these elements being immediate children, I do not want to catch some other nonimmediate children (for example if table > table existed)

Comment: $ = require('cheerio'); $('body > .className > #theID > tag1 > tag2', '<html>...</html>');

Comment: You can't do that. I think it's an ongoing implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
$('html > body > font > table > tbody > tr').html()
```

You can select just like with jQuery selectors

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working then. It seems I thought it wasn't implemented and I remember reading on their website some things weren't imeplemented back then. I'll accept your answer

Comment: When I did answer that I did not check the date. Hope you got that somehow back then :-P